# Create ServiceContract by code

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, wcf, restful-architecture

Is it possible to create a ServiceContract and OperationContract by code and without the attributes.

This is the usual way for creating a ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IPersonService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    Person GetPerson(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    Person InsertPerson(Person person);

    [OperationContract]
    Person UpdatePerson(string id, Person person);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeletePerson(string id);
}
```

Is it possible to create it by code for instance:

ServiceContractAttribute te = new ServiceContractAttribute();
te.append(new OperationContractAttribute);

Comment: what do you want to achieve finally? Implement WCF service or client by simple interface (without attributes) as contract?

Comment: I want to add the OperationContract via code because I want to read a config at start and generate them all from there.

Comment: The config file includes for instance:

OperationContract
GetCarFuel
GetCarHorsePower

Data binding:
GetCarFuel should use or return the dataContract CarFuel
The same for GetCarHorsePower

Comment: How will you implement service in this case? Some class will implement all interface methods, but some of them will not be available via webservice call?